# Android studio run only one java file to generate db

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio

I am using greendao ORM on android. For creating entities and daos you have to write separate java app. Is there any possibility to write it in Android studio and run it? Because what i do now is run eclipse, write db generator and then continue developing in Android studio.

All i need is to write something like this:

```
public class DBGenerator{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Schema schema = new Schema(1,...

        Entity e = schema.addEntity("dummy");
        e.addIdProperty();
        e.addStringProperty("name");

        new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema, "...");
    }
}
```

and hit run to generate files on my hdd. Is that possible in Android Studio?

Comment: I gather you could use IntelliJ IDEA which lets you program Java and Android as the same time.

Comment: Okay, I may have misunderstood your problem. You want to run `DBGenerator` only once per app launch? Or just once after app install? Or you want to run a Java program (this `DBGenerator` class) and get the generated file?

Comment: Hello, I wanted to run a Java program. But I've figured that out at the time. I think that all I had to do is create another Run configuration and set it to build that on Java file as Java application. It is possible to do in Android studio as well :)

Comment: Interesting. Would be better if you post it as answer and accept it. Answering your question might help others now or in future. As they say, sharing is caring. ;)